# How do I access a model outside of a view in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a database site and one of the desired features is to have a button in the navbar that will that the user to a random object in a model. The Django Cookbook gives [an example of a random function for a model](http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/random.html), which I implemented.

However, I cannot seem to call this function from the navbar, since the navbar is in a separate html file that is `included` above the `{% block content %}`, which allows it to appear on every page of the site. However, this means it never sees the model object itself, so I cannot access the function with `{{object.get_random}}` in the navbar.

One idea I had was to use a link in the navbar like this

```
<a href="{% url 'roma:category_list.object.get_random.get_absolute_url' %}">Random Category</a>
```

where `category_list` is the view that has the model passed to it. From there I hoped to grab an object from the model, then the `get_random` function, and finally the url from the object returned from the `get_random` function.
This obviously does not work.
Is there a solution that will allow me to access the function in the navbar html?

Comment: If you ever have the question "this template needs to be included with a specific context", then you should be using a [custom inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing the randomization when rendering the template, I would make a link to a dedicated view with a url like "/random". When that url is called, the view can do the randomization and redirect you to the random model.